# How to access IBM MobileFirst 7.1 default attribute store in session independent mode

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I am working on migrating a IBM MobileFirst 6.3 project to version 7.1 and enabling the 7.1 session independent mode. I have specified the attribute store as the worklight default runtime database.

In the previous version I have used HTTPSession object in HTTP JavaScript adapters to dynamically store some minimal data related to the current user session as shown in the sample code below.

```
    var request = WL.Server.getClientRequest();
    var session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("ID", "123");
    session.setAttribute("UserName", "xxx");
```

As I cannot use session object anymore, are there any WL.Server APIs available for explicitly store/retrieve/remove data from the default attribute store (WL run-time database)? Couldn't find any examples on this. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Can someone please point to an examples on accessing attribute store persisted in the MobileFirst DB2 runtime database?

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge center documents this scenario and solution for 7.1 Session Independent mode here

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_java_server_side_api.html#java_server_side_api__java_rest

**Saving applicative state between requests in Java RESTful adapters**

```
In versions earlier than V7.1.0, developers were able to store the applicative state in the HTTP session, by using the session object, namely request.getSession() (see WL.Server).

If you are working in session-independent mode that became available starting with IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation V7.1.0, the applicative state of the adapter must be persisted outside the session, for example, by using a database such as Cloudant®
```

Sample also is attached in the link above.

Comment: Thanks. I have already referred the cloudant based example. I don't have a cloudant db instance. Looking for a sample that works with the attribute store setup over the default WL run-time database.

Comment: There is No such option like explained in the link above . With Session Independent mode, the applicative state of the adapter must be persisted outside the session,

Comment: Yes I understood that the state should be persisted outside the session. I am focusing more on the alternate database based approach for the same. As I have minimal user information to be kept for each session I am thinking of an approach to use the existing DB2 database, the one used to store the default admin/user data instead of setting up a new Cloudant instance. The approach would be like creating a new table in this database and create an SQL adapter and store and retrieve data with the help of the SQL adapter. Is this implementation practical with MobileFirst 7.1?

Comment: Cloudant is just an example. You can use any mechanism of your choice - another DB, filesytem etc. So you can create another DB and hold your custom data there.  It is not recommended to modify or touch your runtime DB.

Comment: Thanks @VivinK for your input on the DB2 runtime db based approach that I was thinking of. I have one more query related to session independent mode. Where does WL.Server.setActiveUser API store the data when session independent mode is enabled and attribute store is set as database?  Is this API writes to the run-time database?

Comment: It does. But it is part of internals