# Pass data between MobileFirst 8 Java Adapter

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

How we can pass data between MobileFirst 8 Java Adapter for Authenticated user, I tried saving information using

```
public void putInUserSession(String key, String value, AdapterSecurityContext securityContext) {
        if (securityContext != null && securityContext.getAuthenticatedUser() != null) {
            Map<String, Object> hashMap = securityContext.getAuthenticatedUser().getAttributes();
            hashMap.put(key, value);
        }

    }
```

but hashMap.put throws "Unmodifiable Map" Exception

Comment: 1. Can you please ellobarate what kind of information you are trying to store and what duration you expect this to be persisted? 2. did  you try using findClientRegistrationData() / storeClientRegistrationData() in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjava-mfp-server/html/com/ibm/mfp/server/security/external/resource/AdapterSecurityContext.html#storeClientRegistrationData%28com.ibm.mfp.server.registration.external.model.ClientData%29

Comment: I am trying to store String only, and information will be stored till session of user is available. Basically I am trying to add information in session when user is using app(**NOT using Security Check**). As I am not able to  Store information because of **unmodifiable map**

Answer (score 0):

could you please share how you are setting your attributes before saving them.

Here is one of the way  how you can set your attributes in the `protected AuthenticatedUser createUser()` function of the UserLogin security class:

```
private Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 //Here put or save values in attributes   
 @Override
    protected AuthenticatedUser createUser() {
        return new AuthenticatedUser(userId, displayName, this.getName(),attributes);
    }
```

My guess one of the reason why hashMap.put throws "Unmodifiable Map" Exception is because your hashMap is of type `Map<String, Object>` and you are saving values of type `Map<String, String>` which is not possible.
You need to convert `Map<String, Object>` to `Map<String, String>` and then save.

Comment: When I am using Map<String, String> to save information in session using 'AuthenticatedUser(userId, displayName, name, map)', then at compile time only able to get **incompatible types: cannot convert Map of type Object to String**

Comment: Use Map<String,Object> to save information in session .Attributes has to be passed of type Map<String,Object> else you will get error that you have mentioned .

Comment: Yes, I am using same and its working fine, my requirement is to store some data in session from Java adapter(NOT from security test)

Comment: MFP 8.0 session are stateless. Meaning, you cannot store data into http sessions. You will need to resort to other mechanisms to store session data.

Answer (score 0):

As MFP 8.0 session are stateless. (ie) you cannot store data into http sessions. You will need to resort to other mechanisms to store session data. Please refer to the Discussions here [How to access IBM MobileFirst 7.1 default attribute store in session independent mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920246/how-to-access-ibm-mobilefirst-7-1-default-attribute-store-in-session-independent/43932941#4393294)

Knowledge center documents this scenario and solution . For 7.1 this affects Session Independent mode. With 8.0 onwards, Session Independent mode is the only supported mode, and you shd go about doing it this way.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_java_server_side_api.html#java_server_side_api__java_rest

Saving applicative state between requests in Java RESTful adapters

In versions earlier than V7.1.0, developers were able to store the applicative state in the HTTP session, by using the session object, namely request.getSession() (see WL.Server).

If you are working in session-independent mode that became available starting with IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation V7.1.0, the applicative state of the adapter must be persisted outside the session, for example, by using a database such as Cloudant®

Sample also is attached in the link above.

Comment: Did you mean we can't store data in session from Java Adapter using MFP 8?

Comment: Yes, because default and only supported mode in MFP8 is Session Independent mode. and Any adapter specific data has to be persisted outside the session, for example, by using a database such as Cloudant®. Please refer to the link in my answer for a cloudant  based example.

Answer (score 0):

As MFP 8 didn't allow to write data in session from adapter, we can achieve feature using below method

1. Create a Java adapter, lets say "Custom Session"
2. Create a Class level(static) of type HashMap>
3. Key for parent hashMap will be your "Access token"
4. Child hashMap will store data what you want to store, in key value pair
5. Add a scheduler to clean up parent hashMap, for already ended session

So we can create our own custom method to achieve so